# How do I tell Jackson ObjectMapper to use the actual properties instead of camel casing them?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, objectmapper

I have a model(I have omitted getters and setters for brevity) that looks like this:

```
public class ObjkeyInputPayloadItem {
    private String TYPE;
    private String BALL_NAME;
    private String TABLENAME;
    private String PARAMTYPE;
    private String FIELDNAME;
    private String FIELDVALUE;
}
```

I would like to convert it to json using `ObjectMapper` in `jackson` API:

```
String payloadStr = null;
try {
    payloadStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use the `payloadStr` as a camel cased string, how can I tell the `ObjectMapper` to use my bean's properties as they are without converting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JsonProperty annotation on a field to override the name used:

```
@JsonProperty("ballName");
private String BALL_NAME;
```

Comment: ok, this is good but is there a way to do use a property on the `ObjectMapper` or the entire bean?

Comment: Well, I got this far from spending 2 minutes googling it and reading the manual...